# How can I change a field to be obligatory, after the value of one field has changed?

Tags: abap, sap-selection-screens

**I am struggling to find out how to change a field to be obligatory on a selection screen, but I want it to change dynamically based on a checkbox that is marked.**

So for context I have a program with two options in the selection screen. So when I select the first checkbox, I want one of the fields to become obligatory, and when I select the other checkbox for the other option of the program I don't want the field to be obsolete, because the program won't use the value anyway so it does not matter.

Example code:

```
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b1 WITH FRAME. 
PARAMETERS: p_sel AS CHECKBOX,
            p_num TYPE i. 
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b1.    
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b2 WITH FRAME. 
PARAMETERS: p_del AS CHECKBOX,
            p_num2 TYPE i. 
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b2.
"I want to do something like
INITIALIZATION.
LOOP AT SCREEN.
 IF SCREEN-name = p_del AND p_del = abap_true.
  screen-required = 2.
 ENDIF.
MODIFY SCREEN.
ENDLOOP.
```

But this does not seem to work

So when I select `p_del` I want `p_num2` to become OBLIGATORY.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: The selection screen can be changed under the AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT event, but to be able to add a precise answer (with working code), some code from you would be useful (what have you tried?).

Comment: i added a simple example, and i meant obligatory not obsolete sorry

Comment: I have tried this:
INITIALIZATION.
LOOP AT SCREEN.
IF SCREEN-name = p_del.
screen-required = 2.
ENDIF.
MODIFY SCREEN.
ENDLOOP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to skip mandatory fields on selection screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084916/how-to-skip-mandatory-fields-on-selection-screen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added comments to the lines I changed.

```
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b1 WITH FRAME.
PARAMETERS: p_sel AS CHECKBOX USER-COMMAND uc01, " USER-COMMAND technicall necessary that SAP recognises the checkbox click
            p_num TYPE i MODIF ID num. " MODIF ID 'NUM' will be used later
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b1.
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b2 WITH FRAME.
PARAMETERS: p_del  AS CHECKBOX,
            p_num2 TYPE i.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b2.


AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT. " Use this event (not INITIALIZATION)

  LOOP AT SCREEN.
    IF screen-group1 EQ 'NUM'. "MODIF ID used here to turn required on/off 
      IF p_sel EQ abap_true. " If checkbox is checked
        screen-required = '1'.
      ELSE.
        screen-required = '0'.
      ENDIF.
    ENDIF.
    MODIFY SCREEN.
  ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: I would suggest to change it to this. Because earlier it would not turn back to without obligatory.
AT SELECTION-SCREEN ON p_del.
LOOP AT SCREEN.
IF screen-group1 = 'NUM'.
IF p_del = abap_true.
screen-required = 1.
ELSE.
screen-required = 0.
ENDIF.
MODIFY SCREEN.
ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.